# Self Destruct Timer for Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way i can create a thread which ends no matter what after 1 min?

Currently i make a thread to login to a website code is below:

```
 private void runBrowserThread()
    {

        specialCheck = 0;
        var th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var br = new WebBrowser();
            browserCounter = 0;
            br.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            br.Navigate("https://www.xample.com/login");
            Application.Run();

        });

        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
        th.Join();
    }
```

BUT there are a lot of complications in the process so i do not want to code them all , what i am thinking something like a self destruct i can use when making this timer ,so that no matter what if a code is stuck , it does not reach one of the `Application.Exitthread()` it will be stuck there forever so a self destruct after 1 min , Exits the threads so the code can move on.

Because currently i have `Application.Exitthread()` at many places but i sometimes the code is stuck does not reach any, so let me know if there is any way.

Comment: Yes u can: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx BUT, seems to be a ugly hack to me. Why not use exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're already blocking on `th.Join` you could use that to terminate the thread, like so:

```
Boolean success = th.Join( 60 * 1000 ); // 60 second timeout
if( !success ) th.Abort();
```

If you don't want to block on Join, then you could spawn a second watchdog thread that exists only to block on `Join` and perform the timeout and termination task instead of the instigator thread.

Also, use of `Application.ExitThread` isn't good design. Threads can terminate by `return`ing from their entrypoint method - it also removes an unnecessary dependence on the `Application` class and its associated `System.Windows.Forms` assembly.

Comment: Thank you will try it now and also will surely remove Application.ExitThread

Comment: Just a quick question the above statement will terminate the thread no matter what its doing (sitting idle or doing some work)?

Comment: `Abort` causes a `ThreadAbortedException` to be raised on the thread, regardless of its current position. Note that threads don't "sit idle" - they're either suspended (waiting for an IO to complete or blocking) or actively executing something. The `ThreadAbortedException` will be raised regardless.

Comment: Thank you works perfect , but i had to use Application.ExitThread , if i do not even when the work is finished within seconds i have to wait 1 min....

Comment: thread.abort is evil http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation